# How to use Cobertura with Cucumber jvm and Maven?

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, code-coverage

I am looking for the best way to measure code coverage for cucumber tests (cucumber jvm).

I found Cobertura but I don't really know how to use and configure it when it has to measure the code coverage for acceptance test and I can't find anything efficient to do that... (For the moment, I just added the maven plugin corresponding to Cobertura, but I don't know what configuration should be done inside).

Do you have any idea ?

If you think I should use any other tool than Cobertura, please tell me :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you try and use Cobertura, make sure you understand what it does and whether that applies to your case. Cobertura in fact IS a tool that measures the code coverage BUT it is important to understand how it does that.

Cobertura (and jcoverage which it's based on) calculate the percentage of the code covered by tests, meaning that it is actually checking what lines of code were touched! It is very different from the functional (or business domain) test coverage described by BDD tools like Cucumber that you are using.

Saying that, to use Cobertura you have 2 options:

**Single run**

Just include it in your dependencies in pom.xml and run: `mvn 
cobertura:cobertura`

**Integrate into Maven lifecycle**

Add the plugin to your `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>html</format>
            <format>xml</format>
        </formats>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and run `mvn clean site-deploy` to execute the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! I know that Cobertura works like this but, in order to later may use Cucumber for JUnit test, I was asking to do that.